# UIScrollView and Cocos2D 2.0

Tags: uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone, uiscrollviewdelegate

[UIScrollView and Cocos2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457380/uiscrollview-and-cocos2d) has a lot of info, but I'm wondering whether the new version of Cocos2D, which is display link only, will support using UIScrollView as a sort of touch manager? (The approach of http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/21/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview/.)

Comment: This should be asked in the cocos2d forum.

Comment: I have done so, though the question here on StackOverflow seemed like a pretty good resource.